# Ngx-translate with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular2-universal, ngx-translate

I just upgraded from `ng2-translate` (`v. 5.x.x`) to `ngx-translate` (`v. 6.x.x`) in my Angular 2 Universal App.

Before the upgrade I was using this loader ([found here](https://gist.github.com/ocombe/593d21598d988bf6a8609ba5fc00b67e)):

```
class TranslateUniversalLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      observer.next(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`src/i18n/${lang}.json`, 'utf8')));
      observer.complete();
    });
  }
}
```

That I was using like so:

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    CoreModule,
    ViewsModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useClass: TranslateUniversalLoader,
    }),
    UniversalModule
  ]
})
```

After upgrading to `ngx-translate`, however, I get this error in the terminal console (thus, server-side error):

```
Module build failed: Error: /src/app/app.node.module.ts (65,7): 
Argument of type '{ provide: typeof TranslateLoader; useClass: typeof TranslateUniversalLoader; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TranslateModuleConfig'.
```

So anyone knows how to set up a custom loader for server side support with Angular Universal with `ngx-translate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was way easier than expected and detailed in the [migration guide](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md).

In `6.x.x` what is changed that was breaking the code is the expected value passed to `forRoot()`.

Now we need to pass the loader as an object of the `loader` key, like so:

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useClass: TranslateUniversalLoader,
  }
}),
```